# Project from view multiple faces at once but each as a single

Tags: uv, faces

Currently I make fake windows in the building pretty simple: I create a cubes, place them to wall, and then using the Boolean modifier make a "cavity" in the wall:

[image]

The next step is fixing the UV-map for the new face. I need UV just "fill" the area of the face.

The best method for that is `UV unwrap faces` -> `Project Form View (bounds)` (or simply `U` key and then `B` key).

The only problem is that if I choose multiple faces and apply to them `Project from view` they will, like, share their space, so UV will not fill individual face, but will be stretched among them.

Multiple apply (wrong):

[image]

Individual apply (right):

[image]

Because of that I have to apply `Project from view` for each face separately, which is pretty slow.

Can I then somehow apply `Project from view` for multiple faces at once?

---

I tried instead of `Project from view` use `Reset`, but the face is rotated and scaled wrongly:

[image]

---

I also tried `Copy attributes menu` addon, it almost works as I need:

[image]

Initially, I made building using 'Mirror' modifier. But it has been already applied, now building is just a plain geometry, nothing special, so do not know why windows in "mirrored" part of building have that issue.

Comment: Possibly the new answer is better.

Comment: have you tried UV Mapping > Reset and then Ctrl F > Face Data > Rotate UVs for the ones that need to be rotated..?  alse see there's an option in UV editor to Constrain to Image Bounds, you can easily transform and snap faces to bounds with it

Comment: @calambre faces can be different, and also the texture is not squared, so UV need to resized and rotated, not only rotated

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd ok but Face Data > Rotate UVs is not the same as rotating them in UV editor... could write a quick script but I don't fully get the problem

Comment: @calambre ok I will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly this way... activate the shipped add-on 'Copy Attributes Menu'.

- Correct / set the UV mapping for one of your windows
- Select the others by some means (e.g.<kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> > 'Coplanar'), ensuring the good UV winds up active.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > 'Copy Active UV Coordinates'

[image]

Comment: Well, `Reset` does the trick in part of doing the same transformation for each face, but not in the part of correct UV: in case of `Reset`, UV indeed "fills" the face but wrongly: it is rotated and scaled in wrong direction. Of course, I can select a lot faces, apply `Reset` and then rerotate and rescale all of them also at once, but only in case of equal face sizes. If there are different faces, it will not work

Comment: I also updated my question with screenshot

Comment: First, thanks for advice for selecting coplanar faces, it is very usefull. However, Your method still has issues. I updated my question

Comment: I guess that must have to do with your 'Mirror UV' settings in the original modification.. at least, you can rotate all the UVs on one side by 90, in one move?

Comment: Unfortunately no, they actually have the same issue as if I'd apply `Reset`, so I have to rotate and also scale them (because texture has non square form). But I think this answer technically can be accepted

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd you might also look into the 'Magic UV' shipped add-on, but I haven't checked it for being useful in this case..

Comment: Probably will check